# Riding mower goes backwards when I press the gas

Tags: transmission, acceleration, lawnmower

I have a craftsman ride on lawnmower (42 inch deck model 25581). It recently stopped going forward. It goes in reverse when i press the pedal down (reverse) and goes in reverse faster (as if going forward) when i press the pedal forward (gas). In addition it seems the transmission does not fully disengage when i pull the wire/rod in the back that is supposed to disengage the engine/transmission so you can push it around freely. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the pulley belt get reversed in a figure eight?

Comment: Checkef the belts they look ok

Comment: Contact Sears. Or get a new mower. THis model has many problems